# Rails 4 drop down select list different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to Rails so go easy on me :-)

I have 2 models: User and Role:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
  validates_presence_of :role_id
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User has a role_id for the foreign key.

All I'm trying to do is be able to select a role for the user in the users/new form.  I know it's easy, but I cannot seem to figure it out...I've literally read for hours today trying to figure it out.  The drop down select list appears in the view, but it always fails validation (like it shows up, but never actually associates what the user selects with the User.role_id)

Here is what I have in my form partial to show the drop down:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name %>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Maybe I have to use some sort of nested forms, but nothing I have tried seems to work and this is what I currently have.  Do I have to do something in my controller?

Comment: try reversing your associations i.e User should belongs_to role and Role has_many users. Also remove the accepts_nested_attributes_for roles and make sure the roles are created before hand

Comment: You've created a form that allows a user to have only one role (which you are selecting via a dropdown). If you really want a user to have many roles, then you are looking for a very different solution that this one. I'd google "had_many associations in forms" or similar...

Comment: After reversing the roles and removing the accepts_nested_attributes_for, I still get a form validation error.

Comment: I really want to do multiple rows and I initially set up a has_many through relationship, but I thought it might be easier to wrap my brain around a more simple case first.

Comment: Would you be open to using a gem? Something like [easy_roles](https://github.com/platform45/easy_roles) might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If User has many roles, your User model must not have a field: `user_id`, I think, and I hope, that Users Have and Belongs to many Roles. Then you need a third model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  validates_presence_of :role_id, :user_id
end
```

In your User form you can use this to update relations (look: `:role_ids` in plural)

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

And the validation is now in UserRole model.

**Edit**: If you are using Rails 4.x you need to permit params for a collection of role_ids.

```
params.require(:user).permit(:user_field1, :user_field2, ... , role_ids: [])
```